# Check box allways checked in Laravel 4.2

Tags: checkbox, laravel-4

I have a problem with some checkboxes. They are always checked, except if I put "false" in all of them.
I have a function returnig if an "id" is in a array, it works fine. But either it return true or false checkboxes still checked.
This is my function:

```
public  function hasTipologia($id){
    $array = $this->tipologias->lists('id');
    MyHelpers::debugArray([$array,$id,in_array($id,$array)],false);
    return in_array($id,$array);
}
```

MyHelpers show me for debuging the array of ids, the current id of "Tipologia" and if it's in the array or not.

Here you can see that it works
[image: Here you can see that it works]

And the code in my View is:

```
@if(count($tipologias))
    <h4>Tipologías estratégicas</h4>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        @foreach($tipologias as $tipologia)
            <div class="col-md-3">
                {{ Form::checkbox('tipologias[]',$tipologia->id,$formacion->hasTipologia($tipologia->id)===true ?true:false , ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
                {{$tipologia->nombre}}
            </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
@endif
```

I try with different codes, and if I put this one:

```
 $formacion->hasTipologia($tipologia->id)===true ?false:false
```

Still checked, and with this one the same:

```
 $formacion->hasTipologia($tipologia->id)===false ?true:false
```

I have make and @if an then insert two forms, one with true and one with false, and still checked.

Any idea?
Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and finally solved it the following way.

```
 @if(count($tipologias))
  <h4>Tipologías estratégicas</h4>
<div class="col-md-12">
    @foreach($tipologias as $tipologia)
        <div class="col-md-3">
            {{ Form::checkbox('tipologias[]',$tipologia->id,(in_array($tipologia->id ,$formacion->tipologias()->select('tipologias.id')->lists('id')->ToArray()) ? true : false) , ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
 {{$tipologia->nombre}}
        </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
@endif
```

This way you 'll construct the checkboxes and select them or not according to $formacion->tipologias() relationship.Note the select statement select('tipologias.id') in which tipologias should be your table name. I had tried the simplest way

```
{{ Form::checkbox('tipologias[]',$tipologia->id,(in_array($tipologia->id ,$formacion->tipologias()->lists('id')->ToArray()) ? true : false) , ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
```

and I was getting "ambiguous column id" error.So the select method cannot be ommited.